# Laravel login stuck in loop

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I'm having an issue when deploying. When logging into Laravel Nova it just refreshes the login screen over and over again and seems stuck in a loop. whether you enter the wrong or right credentials makes no difference. There are no error messages and reloads the login page.

All working on localhost, and the wrong credentials error message does show up on local if incorrect details entered. Strange issue just generated a server on Forge + DigitalOcean. I don't see what could be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the post form trying to post to http instead of https... if anyone has that issue hope it helped

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use **http** in a development environment you could turn off secure session cookie in **.env** file

```
SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=false
```